# Excel function: "Not Isblank" with "Or" and if date is

Tags: excel, function, date, if-statement

I need a Formula that notify me if one of two cells is empty (or both of them) while if more than 30 days have passed . I used it before but with just one empty cell and it works perfectly:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(H4));"";IF(TODAY()>=C4+30;"Action";""))
```

How can I make it with 2 empty cells?

### Thank you all in advance

I solved it, Thanks for everybody's help. I wanted to update it to check if one cell is blank and another one is NOT blank while more than 30 days have passed. Here is the Formula:
=IF(OR(NOT(ISBLANK(H4));ISBLANK(E4));"";IF(TODAY()>=C4+30;"Action";""))

Answer (score 2):

I can’t really test this due to how Excel localizes its function names (which is so stupid…), but you should be able to combine multiple booleans with `AND` or `OR`, depending on which behavior you want.

If you want to check if two cells are empty you can use `AND(ISBLANK(H4), ISBLANK(H5))` as the condition; if you want to check if both are not empty, you put all that in another `NOT`: `NOT(AND(ISBLANK(H4), ISBLANK(H5))`. Similarly, if you want to check if at least one of the cells is empty, you can use `OR`: `OR(ISBLANK(H4), ISBLANK(H5))`. And if you want to check if none of the cells is empty, you can again again put that in an `AND`.

Answer (score 1):

You can test for both G4 and H4 being filled with `COUNTA`, which counts the cells that have any content, and combine that with your date check in an `AND` statement:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTA(G4:H4)<2;TODAY()>=C4+30);"Action";"")
```